# Automatically hiding a Qt QWidget after the user clicks elsewhere

Tags: qt

I would like to create a `QWidget` that acts like a pop-up, and I am having trouble figuring out how to do it.

I want to create a sidebar/drawer that gets shown when the user clicks a button. The user will briefly interact with child widgets of the sidebar. The tricky part is that I want the sidebar to be hidden automatically when the user clicks elsewhere in the application. Worst case I can require the user to manually toggle the sidebar, but automatically hiding it is convenient.

I tried or investigated:

- [Setting the `Qt::Popup` window flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421699/close-widget-window-if-mouse-clicked-outside-of-it), but the sidebar needs to be a widget, not a separate window.
- Listening for focus events, but I want to support keyboard navigation. The user should be able to Tab to other widgets while the sidebar remains visible. The sidebar should be hidden when the user actually interacts with the other widgets (such as hitting Enter).
- Adding an event filter on the top-level widget, but it doesn't receive events that occur on its children (such as a button being clicked).
- Adding an invisible "overlay" widget over the rest of the application, but I want the user to be able to directly click on other widgets. Capturing clicks in the invisible overlay would require the user to click twice (once to clear the overlay, then again to interact with other widgets).

Is this just not feasible?

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be to install an event filter on the `QApplication` instance itself.  Note, though, that application wide event filters can have a noticeable performance impact so it should only be installed as/when necessary. A mock-up might look something like...

```
class sidebar: public QWidget {
    using super = QWidget;
protected:
    virtual bool eventFilter (QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override
        {

            /*
             * Your stuff goes here...
             */
            if (auto *widget = dynamic_cast<QWidget *>(obj)) { 
                if (isAncestorOf(widget)) {

                    /*
                     * obj refers to a QWidget of some description that is
                     * a child of this sidebar instance.
                     */
                } else {

                    /*
                     * widget _isn't_ a child of this sidebar so may need
                     * to take action (including hiding) depending on the
                     * specifics of widget and the event details.
                     */
                }
            }
            return super::eventFilter(obj, event);
        }
    virtual void showEvent (QShowEvent *event) override
        {
            super::showEvent(event);
            qApp->installEventFilter(this);
        }
    virtual void hideEvent (QHideEvent *event) override
        {
            super::hideEvent(event);
            qApp->removeEventFilter(this);
        }
};
```

Will require a certain amount of experimentation obviously :-)